# Populating an ngrx store with data shared between routes

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store

I have a multi-page form spanning over several routes. All of the routes need the same data shared with them from an API. I can store the response of the API inside `ngrx/store` and trigger the API call using an effect. My question is more about where to initiate the API call. The API call needs to be made once the user is authenticated, which happens on the very first route I hit (before the first part of the multi page form is visited). The two options I've come up with are:

1. Triggering the effect inside each route's component meaning I'll just have to request the information every time I visit a route. A guard will prevent all pages being accessible while the user isn't authenticated.
2. Listen to the authenticated success action inside an effect and make the request to the API there.

I'm sure both are perfectly acceptable and have their trade offs. It'd just be good to get a few opinions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second would be the best, requesting the information on demand ergo when the user is authentified and its allowed to use it makes more sense. Inside of the guard, as u said, you should dispatch the action to load the information before you return true/of(true) to signalize that the route can be activated. The naive approach for this would trigger an information request everythime that you try to activate the guarded route.

Comment: I was siding with the second option. Also, while the data is loading would you suggest using a guard to wait before activating a route or to just check if the API is loading inside each route component and display a spinner or something?

Comment: Normally I would just show an spinner while the information is marked as loading: true inside of my store. In my opinion that is close related to the functionality/characteristics/relation to the information that the component to be rendered has with the information that is requested.